# how to increase the time by one second?

Tags: powershell

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /b %1') DO (

powershell ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%~dA%%~pA\%%~nA.NEWER%%~xA'^).CreationTime = ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%~dA%%~pA\%%~nA%%~xA'^).CreationTime

powershell ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%~dA%%~pA\%%~nA.NEWER%%~xA'^).LastWriteTime = ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%~dA%%~pA\%%~nA%%~xA'^).LastWriteTime
```

above is my code.  it worked.  but the result is that the times are the same

i would like to be able to make the 'modified' files to have a time stamp that is 1 second newer.  thus the question 1 second time increase

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with method `AddSeconds`:

```
^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%~dA%%~pA\%%~nA%%~xA'^).LastWriteTime.AddSeconds(1)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. it worked.  i used your code as is and it didn't work.  i didn't realize that i needed to add ^ before the ( and the ).  after adding ^, it worked.  thanks